# Show that $\left( 1+\dfrac {1} {n}\right) ^{n}$ is increasing

Tags: analysis, limits

I see intuitively $\left( 1+\dfrac {1} {n}\right) ^{n}$ is increasing but I think, it is not obvious. How can I prove this?

*Recall*. If sequence of $\left\{ x_{n}\right\} _{n}$ is increasing then $x_n<x_{n+1}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

*Note that* the limit converges to $e$ (Euler's number).

Comment: Not said correctly. The limit is $e$. You want a proof that the sequence of approximations is increasing. I suspect there's one on this site somewhere.

Comment: The limit is a number (assuming it exists, which it does); it can't be increasing. The underlying sequence can be.

Comment: @anomaly The sequnce is increasing.